# AsyncTask return Object difficulties Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to use an `AsyncTask` to make an API call and map the response to an object I have named `MapInfo`, which is a variable in the `MainActivity`. I then use this `MapInfo`'s field, named polyline, and use the prebuilt URL encoder to use in a different API call. The problem I am having is that I have the `AsyncTask` return the `MapInfo` object in the `PostExecute()`, but the code on the `MainActivity` continues to execute, and I need the `MapInfo` object to be returned first before continuing down the code.

This is in the `MainActivity` :

```
public static MapInfo mapInfo = new MapInfo();

OnCreate() {

    button.setonClick() {

    //some stuff
    new AsyncTask blah = blahblah.execute("");
    //the above returns a singular MapInfo object and assigns it to mapInfo
    String polyline = mapInfo.polyline; //<--This is where the issue is. 
    }
}
```

String polyline is null, and that is used in an API call further down. How should I go about "waiting" for the `AsyncTask` to finish before assigning polyline to the returned object?

**NOTE** : The above block is pseudo-code.

**EDIT** :

I assigned the String, poly, in the post execute, but the same error still occurred. I am doing more than just using the String polyine in the `MainActivty`, I am using the returned `MapInfo` object in `MainActivity` to assign `TextViews` and then use polyline in a different API call to download an image. Should I change from an `AsyncTask` to just the API call since I only need 4 fields from the entire `JSONobject`?

**RED** arrow is attempt to assign in `MainActivity`.

**BLUE** arrow is attempt to assign in `OnPostExecute`.

[snip from Android Studio CLICK ME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJrm4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AsyncTask` execute the task in background thread which is performed asynchronously.
    Two way to get result after task execute:

1. Use `blahblah.execute("");`
      and get result inside onPostExecute

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(MapInfo mapInfo) {
      super.onPostExecute(mapInfo);
      String polyline = mapInfo.polyline;
   }
   ```

   **OR**
2. Use like

   ```
   MapInfo mapInfo = blahblah.execute("").get();
   String polyline = mapInfo.polyline;
   ```

   In this way no need to catch result in onPostExecute(-)

Comment: The problem was on the OnPostExecute(). I was trying to assign a global variable in the MainActivity from the AsyncTask, but for whatever reason it wasn't working. Using your #2 above worked (except I did mapInfo.getPolyline()). Thank you.

Also note that the .get() method requires you to use a try-catch with multiple exception types IF anyone else runs into this issue and is getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncTask` will execute the task in background thread which is performed asynchronously. Placing the `String polyline = mapInfo.polyline;` immediately after the `new AsyncTask blah = blahblah.execute("");` will execute it immediately since control will trigger the `AsyncTask` and continue executing next statements

If you need to execute `String polyline = mapInfo.polyline;` after task is executed then place it in `onPostExecute()` as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final MapInfo mapInfo) {
   super.onPostExecute(mapInfo);
   ...
   final String polyline = mapInfo.polyline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `AsyncTask` for the API call as API services(Retrofit, Volley, etc) already works in the background thread.

As `AsyncTask` and API Call services works in different threads the data is not updated accordingly.

Instead you should use the method `onSuccess` method of the API to set the result in the `MainActivity`

Comment: The problem with this is the network connection. It throws an error b/c it can't run on main thread. I tried just making the AsyncTask a class with a method called run, but it threw that error. I COULD go this route but it would be more of a band-aid to the problem rather than a solution.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask will be handled in seperate thread, main thread continues to next line.
MapInfo object is not yet stored with API data so it has polyline as null.

**try like this**

When button is clicked start AsyncTask to load MapInfo. In onPostExecute() do your remain works like assigning to textviews and downloading image.

```
new AsyncTask<String, Void, MapInfo>() {
        @Override
        protected MapInfo doInBackground(String... strings) {
            MapInfo m = null;
            try {
                //handling of Mapinfo api
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return m;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(MapInfo info) {
            mapInfo = info;
            if (mapInfo != null) {
                //assign to textviews
                //download image task (background thread)
            }
        }
    }.execute();
```